# Keras custom layer/constraint to implement equal weights

Tags: python-3.x, keras, keras-layer

I would like to create a layer in Keras such that:

> y = Wx + c

where W is a block matrix with the form:

[image]

A and B are square matrices with elements:

[image]
[image]

and c is a bias vector with repeated elements:

[image]

How can I implement these restrictions? I was thinking it could either be implemented in the MyLayer.build() when initializing weights or as a constraint where I can specify certain indices to be equal but I am unsure how to do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define such W using `Concatenate` layer.

```
import keras.backend as K
from keras.layers import Concatenate

A = K.placeholder()
B = K.placeholder()

row1 = Concatenate()([A, B])
row2 = Concatenate()([B, A])
W = Concatenate(axis=1)([row1, row2])
```

Example evaluation:

```
import numpy as np

get_W = K.function(outputs=[W], inputs=[A, B])
get_W([np.eye(2), np.ones((2,2))])
```

Returns

```
[array([[1., 0., 1., 1.],
        [0., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 0.],
        [1., 1., 0., 1.]], dtype=float32)]
```

To figure out exact solution you can use `placeholder`'s `shape` argument. Addition and multiplication are quite straightforward.

Comment: I'm new to Keras so please correct me if I'm wrong. Aren't placeholders used for the inputs? I would like the elements of W to be trainable parameters.

Comment: I used them because I wanted to show a test. You can do this with any tensors (as long as A and B are of appropriate shape, for example square matrices).

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you!